# Conversions of real numbers

Tags: algorithms, real-numbers, fractional-part

Given functions $f:\Bbb Z_+\to \Bbb Z_n $ and $g:Z_+\to \Bbb Z_m$ and suppose

$$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(k)\cdot n^{-k}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty g(k)\cdot m^{-k}$$

Is there a method to express $f(k)$ with $\{g(i)\}_{i\in\Bbb Z_+}$ for each k?

That is, how to convert infinite fractions with different number basis?

I now how to do to convert finite sequences, e.g. $0.321_8$ to decimal $(12_8=10_{10})$:

```
321x12= 4052  4
052x12= 0644  0
644x12=10150  8
150x12= 2020  2
020x12= 0240  0
240x12= 3100  3
100x12= 1200  1
200x12= 2400  2
400x12= 5000  5
000x12= 0
```

So $0.321_8=0.408203125_{10}$

Comment: If you know how to do it for finite sequences then you know how to do it for infinite sequences too...

Comment: @whacka: Yes, you are right. I was simplifying the more general question of other bases than 2. I will edit. Thanks!

Comment: @whacka: No, wait a minute! To get the first decimal digit you'll have to multiply the infinite string with $1010$. How to do that?

Comment: Multiply with $1010$? Huh? To get any given number of digits in a new base, there is a predictable cutoff point where you can truncate the number to a certain number of digits in the original base and then convert that finite sequence of digits to the new base.

Comment: @whacka: prove that it works in an answer and I'll certainly accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @whacka: I'll guess your method works for the first collection of digits, but how to go on to get an arbitrarily number of digits?

Comment: @whacka: What you say is false. For instance, if you have to convert decimal $x=0.333....$ to base $3$, you can't know even the first digit unless you know whether that sequence of $3$'s continues for ever, and if not, whether the first deviating digit is less than or greater than $3$.

Comment: @TonyK - you're right, that is a wrench in the plan I was suggesting. Unfortunately there is no epsilon for which knowing a number to within epsilon tells us the number's first digit.